# installing puppy linux bootable on usb flash: does the size of the drive matter? [solved]

Tags: memory, installation, usb-flash-drive, puppylinux

While looking for information about puppy, I read this:

""To give an idea of what is "enough" RAM, a PC with 256M RAM matches well with a 128M Flash drive. The pup100 file will be about 60M, and there's enough RAM for everything to load into ramdisk. On the other hand, a 256M Flash drive would have a 180M pup100 file which would be too big. With a 256 flash-drive 512MB RAM are good to keep all in RAM.""

(I read it) here: http://puppylinux.org/wikka/HowPuppyWorks
(are links allowed? I just looked through the "Taur" and didn't see anything)

and now I'm concerned that if I install puppy onto a flash drive (the smallest I have is 4GB), it won't load into ram properly. I'm trying to use as little ram as possible, while also writing to the drive as infrequently as possible (puppy is supposed to do the latter after first boot). max ram is 256 until I upgrade. Is the above paragraph accurate? Is it poorly worded or missing information? Is it out of date? is there some special method to installing puppy on a large(er than a floppy disk) flash drive?

(don't give me slack about the ram please. it's a thrift store pet project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely go with larger flash drive.
If PC has at least 128 Mb of RAM `PuppyLinux` will happily fit in ramdisk.
To keep changes, settings or anything else you want to keep while working in `PuppyLinux`, it will be saved to a virtual ext2 filesystem and saved as pup100 file (think about it as it is your personal non volatile storage). This file (pup100) will be loaded to the ramdisk on next boot and saved back on shutdown to the flash drive, so all your session's changes will be kept. pup100 used to avoid writes to the flash drive and here is a moment where you need to make decision - if you have enough RAM you can choose size of virtual storage bigger or smaller, depending on your needs, but keep in mind that any programs that will start in PuppyLinux also need some amount of memory.

You can use any flash drive bigger than PuppyLinux+pup100 file but the actual virtual storage would be limited to the size of pup100 file you choose since it need to fit to the RAM on targeted computer.

You can use multiple scenarios on bigger flash drives. Since pup100 is just a file, you can rename it and `PuppyLinux` will create a new one, this way you can swap these files by simply renaming it and use it later as a different sessions before starting `PuppyLinux`.
The same way you can run `PuppyLinux` on different computers that has different amount of RAM, just name pup100 file such way you can recognize it and simply rename it to pup100 before starting or choose the smallest size of virtual storage (pup100 file that would be loaded to RAM) and it will work across all computers you use.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I knew I was missing something.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help you